# Displaying WCF Web service operations

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis-7, operations

So I've created a WCF service application and hosted it on IIS7. It currently has a few test 'helloworld' methods. When I run it in my browser I get this screen:
[image]

Now the service itself works great, but how can I display the operations like this:
[image]

Thanks to marc_s for the link: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=399 which I've followed so my web config is now setup like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServer.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServer.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="HelpBehaviour" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="HelpBehaviour">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, this only works locally. When I publish to my server on IIS7 I get a 404 error page when I click on the help link. Does anyone know why this is, or has come across it before?

(Last bit was solved by running: `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru`)

Comment: You are best using the WCFTestClient to test WCF in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE (for VS 2010)

Comment: This was the first thing I did: which works fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a WCF service with a SOAP binding, you're unfortunately out of luck: there's no way in WCF out of the box to get a listing similar to ASMX with all the services.

With REST binding (`webHttpBinding`) and .NET 4.0, you can have an automatic help page generated which lists the URI templates, the HTTP methods supported and so forth. You can also tweak that page to a certain degree.

In order to have that automatic help page generated, you need to define (and reference) an endpoint behavior:

```
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="HelpBehavior">
           <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
       </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Then reference that behavior from your `webHttpBinding` endpoint, and you're done.

Read all about it:

- [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)
- [Windows Communication Foundation 4.0 - New REST Features](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=399)
- [Clients and the Automatic Help Page in WCF WebHttp Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/11/clients-and-the-automatic-help-page-in-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx)

Comment: +1 I was just writing the same answer. I would only add that help page URL for REST service has sufix /help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx

Comment: How can I get the automatic help page generated? I'm using .NET 4.0 and was attempting to do REST services but the web.config doesn't have any endpoints defined. Do I have to write these myself?

Comment: Where it talks about "default endpoints", do they get used when none are defined then?

Comment: @ing0: yes, if you define no endpoints at all, WCF 4 will kick in some default endpoints, based on your base address(es) defined, and your service contract. As soon as you define even a single endpoint, then only that endpoint of your is used

Comment: Right ok thanks, I need to write an endpoint which I then reference my help behaviour too.

Comment: Thanks for providing the info I needed marc!